# Launch different tkinter version from python app compiled with pyinstaller on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tcl, pyinstaller

I have a tkinter GUI that allows me to start any kind of program:

```
# main_app.py
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess

root = tk.Tk()

cmd_entry = tk.Entry(width=50)
cmd_entry.pack(side='left')

def run_script():
    sp = subprocess.run(cmd_entry.get().split(), shell=True)

run_btn = tk.Button(text="Run Command", command=run_script)
run_btn.pack(side='left')

root.mainloop()
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I can start another tkinter script from this window, for instance:

```
# dummy_app.py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

It even works when starting `dummy_app.py` with a different version of python. For example, I can start `main_app.py` with Python 3.10.8 and run the following:

```
C:\Path\to\python3.9\python.exe dummy_app.py
```

However, if I compile `main_app.py` into an executable with pyinstaller (v5.6.2):

```
pyinstaller.exe .\main_app.py --onefile
```

Then I get the following error when trying to run `C:\Path\to\python3.9\python.exe dummy_app.py` from `main_app.exe`:

```
C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI76562/tcl/init.tcl: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.9, need exactly 8.6.12
version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.9, need exactly 8.6.12
    while executing
"package require -exact Tcl 8.6.12"
    (file "C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI76562/tcl/init.tcl" line 19)
    invoked from within
"source C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI76562/tcl/init.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list source $tclfile]"


This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

`python dummy_app.py` works fine however.

Why does the tcl version has to be the same when starting the script from the compiled executable? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pyinstaller set the TCL/Tk path into environment variable, So you can set the env argument to subprocess.

```
def run_script():
    env = os.environ.copy()
    if 'TCL_LIBRARY' in env:
        del env['TCL_LIBRARY']
    if 'TK_LIBRARY' in env:
        del env['TK_LIBRARY']
    sp = subprocess.run(cmd_entry.get().split(), shell=True, env=env)
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much! How did you come up with this? I can't seem to find the relevant doc...

Comment: For others stumbling upon the same problem: the part of the pyinstaller code that sets those variables can be seen on [Github](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/7d8ea9dcb60bf15fe46a7f0b0bdb711d823dd470/tests/functional/scripts/pyi_lib_tkinter.py#L12)

Answer (score 2):

The version of the Tcl support scripts used inside Tkinter must exactly match the version of the Tcl and Tk binary libraries used. Bugfixes may be applied in either location, but the version matching must be exact; they're matched parts a single software product.

The workaround is not to cross-match. If you bind the version in one place (e.g., with linking options) then you must bind it in the other (e.g., by shipping the script files).

We're working on making future versions (8.7 onwards) have this binding done at link time; almost all scenarios don't need significant rewriting of internal scripted parts of Tcl and Tk's implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So pyinstaller binds the TCL/Tk version at compile time while the python scripts do it at runtime? (Or link time I'm not familiar with this kind of terminology)